# What does "var cc = cc = cc || {};" line do in Cocos2D?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone

I'v tried to find the reason of using this line of code

```
var cc = cc = cc || {};
```

in Cocos2D JavaScript library for example in [this](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/blob/master/cocos2d/CCCamera.js#L26) place, but I couldn't find any reasonable reason. Single assignment in terms of settings a default value would be ok but double assignment? Anyone know the reason of that?

Comment: looks like a mistake to me

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a mistake.

Comment: Maybe it is evaluated as `var cc = (cc = cc || {});`, so it simply sets local and global `cc` variables?

Comment: @VisioN: Tested - nope. `var` declarations are lifted to the top of their scope, so with or without brackets, this refers to the local `cc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one has been annoying me, so I have has a play and done some tests and here are my findings.

I will show two different pieces of script, that produce two different results, thus explaining why somebody may use one over the other. The reasons for using either however is down to the coder and will be based on the effect they want to happen.

Note, for example purposes I will use actually values rather than empty objects.

Normally, you might expect to see the following example in use:

```
var cc = cc || 1;
```

This creates a new variable called `cc` and gives either the value of an existing (within the same scope) variable, or a default value of `1`. This method will NOT change the original variable, although in practice it will seemingly have the effect that it has changed as you can not subsequently reference the original due to the fact it has the same name.

This can be tested by using different variable names for example:

```
var aa;
alert(aa);
var cc = aa || 1;
alert(aa);
alert(cc);
```

([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/HzKhJ/))
Here you can see that `aa` never changes.

Next we look at the code in question:

```
var cc = cc = cc || 1;
```

This will actually change the original variable AND create a new local one. Again, it is not easy to see the effects while the variables have the same name. However, if we do the same name change as above, we can see the real effect:

```
var aa;
alert(aa);
var cc = aa = aa || 1;
alert(aa);
alert(cc);
```

([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/HzKhJ/1))
This time we can see that `aa` does get changed.

In conclusion, you may never actually see any effect from using one over the other (with the same variable names), but I am curious as to what effects would happen if it is possible to reference the original somewhere, prior to assignment, and therefore the choice of which to use would actually have an effect. I will see if I can find something to show this in action.

Comment: Ok, it's the best code explanation for me but the reason of usage it still remains. Why the hell anyone used it? :)

Answer (score 2):

The code is equivalent to the following:

```
var cc;
cc = cc || {};
cc = cc;
```

which obviously is a mistake.

**UPDATE.** I did more research on this topic and here's an interesting thing:

Whenever you use `var` keyword it creates a new variable in current scope unless it already exists **in current scope**. Basically this code:

```
var cc = 1;
function test() {
    var cc = cc || {};
    return cc;
}
test();
```

will always produce `{}`, no matter what the initial value of `cc` ( in global scope ) is. In particular this code:

```
var cc = [expression];
```

is equivalent to:

```
var cc;
cc = [expression];
```

although `var cc;` creates new variable **only if** `cc` does not exist in current scope.

**UPDATE 2.** What operation takes precedence is confusing because in OP's code both `=` signs actually are not the same. The first one denotes variable declaration, because there is a `var` keyword before it. The second one is an assignment. That's why

```
var x = y = z;
```

is equivalent to

```
var x;
y = z;
x = z;
```

( note that `var` keyword applies only to `x` ) while

```
x = y = z;
```

is equivalent to

```
y = z;
x = z;
```

( note that operation `y=z` returns `z`, which doesn't really matter (it could be `y` obviously) but it is worth noting )

**CONCLUSION:** Variable declaration on the left side **always** comes before evaluation of the right side and assignment of the right side to the left side.

Comment: Wouldn't it be equivalent to `cc = cc || {}; var cc = cc;`

Comment: @musefan I'm not 100% sure how it works under the hood, but it seems that variable declaration takes precedence over other operations. This also proves that such constructions should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

**10 years later:**
So funny to come back and look at this question a decade later. Now it's obvious to me that this is **not a mistake** but a shortcut to set the local `cc` variable to the same value as the outer variable `cc` while initializing the outer variable if needed. Consider this example:

```
// given that foo = 5
var bar = foo = foo || 1  // bar = 5

// given that foo = undefined
var bar = foo = foo || 1  // foo = 1, bar = 1
```

another way of expressing it would simply be:

```
foo = foo || 1
var bar = foo
```

However, this construction will throw an error if the outer variable is **not defined** (which in JS is not the same as *undefined*).

---

**Original comment:**

This code is clearly a mistake. What the author had in mind was probably to set both global and inner scope variables to the same value but this expression will always fail. Not only does it fail setting the outer variable, it resorts to always return `{}`.

The reason why this expression fails is that declared variables are set to *undefined* before assignment. Since this line of code tries to assign a variable with the same name as itself and since JavaScript evaluates inner scope variables first, `cc` will always resolve to its *undefined* inner self during the moment of assignment, which negates the logical evaluation and returns `{}`.

Another way to see it in code:

```
var cc;                 //cc is set to 'undefined'

cc = cc || {};          //which becomes equivalent to:

cc = undefined || {};   //which finally evaluates to:

cc = {}
```